# How to set a boolean in User Defaults in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code and I am trying to have a tutorial at the beginning of my game which only plays one time so I have a Boolean variable set to become true once the tutorial has been completed but for some reason the value is staying as false. I even have it print the value of tutorial and it comes out as false even though the line right before is a line setting the value to true. Why is it doing this?

```
let tutorial = UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "tutorial")


if tutorial == false {
        introSequence()
}

if rightIntroButton.contains(location) {
    UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "tutorial")                                                       
    //tutorial = true
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "tutorial")
    print(tutorial)                                             
}
```

Comment: Try calling `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` after set the key.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1408905-setbool?language=objc

Comment: What's with the messed up indentation? By the way, it's probably not a bad idea to extract the user defaults keys (`"tutorial"`) into a centralized variable, that let's you more easily change them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Boolean variable set to become true once the tutorial has
>   been completed but for *some reason* the value is staying as false.

Thea reason is: each time you are creating a new object for accessing the UserDefaults (`UserDefaults()`), instead, you should use [standard](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard) *Singleton* object:

> Returns the **shared** defaults object.

So, replace `UserDefaults()` with `UserDefaults.standard`.

Comment: I tried doing this but the tutorial variable is still being printed as false even after I changed UserDefaults() to UserDefaults.standard.

Comment: Then, I encourage you to debug your code, add some breakpoints and check when the value of `tutorial` has been edited.